# Three- dimensional histogram with color

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, histograms

I have data, that has the following form: i x y z c ; where i is a number, that goes from 1 to N, x,y,z are thought of as coordinates, and c is supposed to be a value that I want to present as color.

I have some struggles because most of the 3-dimensional histograms are actually 2-dimensional "heatmaps" where the value is presented as height, but this is not a true 3-dimensional histogram.

How can I create a box of the interval [0,1]x[0,1]x[0,1], and at coordinate (x,y,z) put down a dot and color it with C (for all points)?

The colors should range between some range (let's say after rescaling between [+/-1]) and should be colored dark blue/red for +/- 1 and lighter as it gets closer to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found what I wanted using a different function:

data = Import["your_file_path.txt", "Table"];

(* Extract columns x, y, z, and c *)
extractedData = data[[All, {2, 3, 4, 6}]];

(* Filter data based on the condition c > -0.0001 *)
filteredData = Select[extractedData, #[[4]] > -0.0001 &];

(* Plot the filtered data with ListDensityPlot3D *)
plot = ListDensityPlot3D[filteredData, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic];

(* Export the plot to a PNG file *)
Export["output_plot.png", plot]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**

***"i want the largest positive to be dark blue, small positive to be light blue, small negative to be light red and large negative to be dark red"***

```
SeedRandom[1];
ixyzc = MapIndexed[Flatten@*Reverse@*List]@RandomReal[1, {10, 4}];
```

Change the last column of input data so that it runs from -1 to 1:

```
ixyzc2 = MapAt[Rescale[#, MinMax@ixyzc[[All, -1]], {-1, 1}] &, 
   ixyzc, {All, -1}];
```

Use the last column of input data to specify colors running thru the color list `{Darker@Red, Red, LightRed, White, LightBlue, Blue, Darker@Blue}` as the value of last column runs from -1 to 1:

```
styleddata2 = Style[{#2, #3, #4}, Blend[
 Thread[{Subdivide[-1, 1, 6], 
   {Darker@Red, Red, LightRed, White, LightBlue, Blue, Darker@Blue}}], #5]]& @@@ 
  ixyzc2;


ListPointPlot3D[styleddata2, BoxRatios -> 1, 
 BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[15]]
```

[image]

Attach last column values as labels to verify that colors and values match as desired:

```
styledlabeleddata2 = MapThread[
  Callout[#, Round[#2, .1], LabelStyle -> 14, Appearance -> "Frame"] &]@
  {styleddata2, ixyzc2[[All, -1]]};

ListPointPlot3D[styledlabeleddata2, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[15]]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[styleddata2 /. Style[a_, b_] :> {b, Sphere[a, .05]}, 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
SeedRandom[1];
ixyzc = MapIndexed[Flatten@*Reverse@*List]@RandomReal[1, {10, 4}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0.817389, 0.11142, 0.789526, 0.187803},   
>  {2, 0.241361, 0.0657388, 0.542247, 0.231155},   
>  {3, 0.396006, 0.700474, 0.211826, 0.748657},   
>  {4, 0.422851, 0.247495, 0.977172, 0.825163},   
>  {5, 0.925275, 0.578056, 0.29287, 0.208051},   
>  {6, 0.580474, 0.128821, 0.306427, 0.712012},   
>  {7, 0.390582, 0.819967, 0.325351, 0.59326},   
>  {8, 0.518774, 0.169013, 0.472565, 0.807161},   
>  {9, 0.0118355, 0.316876, 0.789804, 0.011978},   
>  {10, 0.391276, 0.458902, 0.458845, 0.727517}}
> ```

#### 1. [`ListPointPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPointPlot3D.html)

```
styleddata = Style[{#2, #3, #4}, Hue@#5] & @@@ ixyzc;


ListPointPlot3D[styleddata, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

If you want to add labels:

```
styledlabeleddata =  Callout[Style[{#2, #3, #4}, Hue@#5], #] & @@@ ixyzc;


ListPointPlot3D[styledlabeleddata, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

#### 2. [`BubbleChart3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart3D.html)

```
labeleddata = Association[# -> {##2} & @@@ ixyzc];

BubbleChart3D[labeleddata, 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue@#4 &), 
 BubbleSizes -> {.1, .1}]
```

[image]

```
BubbleChart3D[labeleddata, ColorFunction -> (Hue@#4 &), 
 BubbleSizes -> {.1, .1}, ChartLabels -> Automatic,  LabelStyle -> 16]
```

[image]

#### 3. [`Graphics3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html)

```
g3ddata = {Hue@#5, Sphere[{#2, #3, #4}, .1]} & @@@ ixyzc;

Graphics3D[g3ddata, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer!

How can I remove the text from the dots?

Comment: @Kregnach, please see the updated version.

Comment: One last question, and I stop! How to set the colors, let's say to range between red and blue? The color in the data is +/- something (not too large), i want the largest positive to be dark blue, small positive to be light blue, small negative to be light red and large negative to be dark red ?

Comment: @Kregnach, please see the update.

Comment: Thank you! I updated the question to represent the changes!

Comment: It turns out, that what i want is covered in the ListDensityPlot3D package, so im working on a solution right now, but if you have a fast solution to it with that, that could be helpful! :)